# How do I wrap a view row inside a <div>?

Tags: views

I have bad-designed a view, and the result is that I have the following scheme:

- Field 1: Category (taxonomy)
- Field 2: Node title
- Field 3: Image
- Field 4: Other data (PHP processed).

The problem is that I need field 1 to appear just once for a group of nodes and not always. As I had to redo all the View, I have made the following process, please tell me if there is a better solution.

Instead of not displaying field 1, grouping by that, etc., as I have some PHP process on it, I do the following:

In views-view-fields.tpl.php I identify the category, and prepend *[[BEGIN]]*. I identify the last field and append *[[END]]*.

In views-view-unformated.tpl.php I replace [[BEGIN]] and [[END]] with `<div>` wrappers; depending on the valued inside (`preg_match`), I make the category title  appear just once at the beginning of the list of products.

Please tell me if that is a valid approach (it works) or it should be more desirable to re-draw the view (hours of changing fields, logic, etc.).

The string replacement outputs an additional `<div>` which wraps all the complete row of fields. This I had in the view as the field 1 was just another field and did not encapsulate anything. Maybe even if I would set it as grouping field it didn't encapsulate anything. The result I want (and get) is:

```
<div class="other-class" id="category-119"> divs and HTML stuff from the view  </div>
```

The only easy and fast way of doing a `<div>` encapsulation of the row is using those delimiters in the template files.

Comment: Can you also post your expected output?

Comment: Added at the end of the edited answer. Basically I get a warping div with some codification that I can not get by any other means, but surely there must be a (far) better way of doing this.

Comment: do you want to wrap the div in all views row or each rows? just want to clarify before answering it.

Comment: All views rows til the end is marked. In fact, I put just a unique delimited [BEGIN] as it does not always appear (category is not shown, php logic). When I find [BEGIN] I wrap inside an additional div. By using counters I take care of the closing div tags.

Comment: You want field 1 to appear in row 1 only? Is that your question?

Comment: Well, there is a mixture of things I do because of bad design. I put a field which in the Views appears always, and with preprocess php code, I set it to appear just once. Later when it appears I mark it with a tag which later use to warp inside a div, enclosing a bunch of rows. It is clearly bad desing, I am sure that the enclosing div could have been set at the View GUI. By not grouping there or something I have the category field, which must appear just once, appearing in all rows, and I have to do all the logic commented.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add field and `Exclude from Display`.
2. Add `Global: Text area` in the **header**.
3. Check `Use replacement tokens from the first row`
4. Enter the row pattern
5. Use css to make it look part of the first row

That will output the first row's field in the header.

Comment: I don't see how the Header will be repeated after a few rows, when the Category changes, it seems something that goes just once at the very beginning of the View. Also, I have used the replacement tokens, and get "Content: Category" literally written when I use [field_category]. I would have expected the full pattern text be replaced by the category name, and not by the literal "Content: Category".

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you only mentioned grouping as a way to give the field.. Didn't realise there were multiple types.

Comment: And what about the literal "Content: Category" being shown? What is its value? May it be a bug?

Comment: What happens with [title] or [nid] ?

Comment: Title is the only one that behaves as expected (see replacement by Cold fusion of [title]: [Content: Category]">[Content: Category] Title: Cold fusion NID: [nid]

Comment: And you have the fields added to the view? Sounds weird..

Comment: My fault, I had set the replacement in the own field besides the Global Area. Now it is working right, but this will not work because of the multi-rows.

Comment: Do you know how many groupings there will be? Could just do attachment views and filter each by category.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44291/discussion-between-cesar-and-niall-murphy).